# Excel VBA Find Date - Run Time Error

Tags: vba, excel, date, find

I have a problem with my VBA code and I hope someone can help me. What I'm trying to do here is the following:

I have a worksheet (Sheet 1) with data that gets updated every day. In order to preserve this data, I want to copy and store the source data on another worksheet (Sheet 2). Sheet 2 has columns for every day. When I run the code, it should find the column for today's date in Sheet 2 and paste the data underneath the column header. No rocket science, right?

Now my problem: In general, the code works fine. It usually does what it's supposed to do. But sometimes, out of nowhere, it gives an error:

> Run time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

on the Offset function. I figured out that this error occurs because my find function returns "Nothing". But I have no idea why it doesn't return anything... I already checked for a few things:

- The targetheader in Sheet 2 does contain all the required dates
- The date format in Sheet 2 is mm/dd/yyyy which should be the right format

Furthermore, when I slightly adjust the code, it sometimes starts working again for a while.. Very strange. Anyone an idea what might go wrong here?

```
    Sub Save_Login_Data()

    Dim Source As Range
    Set Source = Worksheets("Data Sheet 1").Range("AV12:AV29")
    Dim TargetHeader As Range
    Set TargetHeader = Worksheets("Data Sheet 2").Range("D119:HF119")
    Dim Today As Date
    Today = CDate(Date)

    With TargetHeader
    Dim TodaysDate As Range
    Set TodaysDate = Range("D119:HF119").Find(What:=Today, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = TodaysDate.Offset(1, 0)

        If TodaysDate = Today Then
        Source.Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    End If

    End With
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error would suggest that for whatever reason, the `Range.Find` is not locating the date. The most likely reason is that you're searching for a date in one format, but the cells contain it in a different format - either visually or actually as the value. So the resultant `TodaysDate` contains nothing, which is not a range, and therefore cannot be offset from. Try trapping this possibility with an `If Not TodaysDate Is Nothing Then...`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The weird thing is that the code does not seem to be structurally wrong. It runs perfectly for a while, and then suddenly drops the error. I could even run it ten times on one day, and it could go alright for 9 times but show an error the 10th time.. I added the If Not Then statement as you suggested. The code now runs perfectly again, thanks! Let's hope the error won't come back this time :)

Comment: It doesn't sound like this will fix it, but you might also want to cycle through your dates on the sheet to make sure there's no time values attached. `For Each cell In Range(DateRange).Cells
    cell.Value = Int(cell.Value)
Next cell`

Comment: It's not going to choose random times for the errors, there has got to be something changing between the times it work and the times it doesn't.  Also, for troubleshooting purposes, try adding a line just before the Offset line like: `MsgBox TodaysDate.Address`.  It will popup the range that it's trying to offset from.  Is it the cell that you expected?  And, are you sure the dates appearing on the worksheet are actually stored as (and formatted as) dates (as opposed to text?)  Another one to try is `MsgBox(IsDate(TodaysDate.Value))`. If it doesn't say `TRUE` then it's not a date.

Comment: One more thing, read this [Debugging Guide](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) by the marvelous Chip Pearson and try out the "**Stepping Through Code**" section to help determine the cause of the error.

Comment: Are you the only user of the document? If not, is it possible that another user has a different default date format? That might cause some issues, especially if it's DD/MM/YYYY vs MM/DD/YYYY which makes `Finds` really awkward. Might be worth removing all formatting - i.e. dates as pure serial numbers (or having a hidden row without it at least) to perform searches on..?

Comment: @JohnInk What exactly does
        Int(cell.Value) 
do? I'm not that familiar with VBA to be honest.

Comment: Datetime values are stored as a count of days since January 1900, ie. right now is 43,106.24089, where 43,106 is the date and .24089 is how far we're into today (the time). `Int()` just drops to the right of the decimal, so you're only looking at the date. You'd do this because if you format a cell to only show the date, it still keeps but doesn't show the time value, so in vba it may prevent a match. To see if you have any time values, format the fields as time values. They should all read 12:00 AM.

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks for your answer! Yeah I check, double checked and triple checked the date formats and there doesn't seem to bu any problem there. The problem with the messagebox idea is that when the code is working correctly,  it will always be the expected cell. When the code is not working, the messagebox won't work either because "TodaysDate" then equals "Nothing". However, the code has been running perfectly for days now :) Also thanks for mentioning the Debugging Guide!

Comment: @CLR Yes I am the only user of the document. Good suggestion though! I will try to use the hidden row with pure serial numbers when it crashes again

Comment: @JohnInk Ah thank you! Very helpful!